# Error: p-button (and p-password) is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have primeng installed via `npm install primeng --save`

In package.json, in both dependencies and devDepencencies, primeng is at `^12.0.1`

In angular.json, I have put in the relevant styles.

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  //...
],
```

In login.module.ts vimI have put the relevant codes:

```
import {PasswordModule} from 'primeng/password';
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/button';

@NgModule({
   ...
   imports:[
   ...
   ButtonModule,
   PasswordModule
   ]
  })
```

It is hard to copy and paste code from vm, but I typed out respectively:

```
<p-password></p-password>
<p-button></p-button>
```

My login module is in login folder nested with app folder

Edit:
p-password and p-button works when it is in app module but in login module,it doesn't not work.

I have set app routing module to route "" to login module.

Edit: I ended up just merging the login component with  app module and removed login module. I am so tired of this.

Comment: you can use https://codesandbox.io/ to provide a working example.

Comment: Here is working sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-button-demo-cq1rn9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts. compare your code with this working sample

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old topic, but I have faced the same issue lately. In my case, I forgot to add LoginModule at the level of AppModule itself in the imports array.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        ...
        LoginModule,
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to import CommonModule, on LoginModule

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
imports: [CommonModule, ButtonModule, PasswordModule]});
```

I had the same Issue, and the solution it's import the CommonModule.